# Как использовать нулевое кольцо привилегий в Windows 7/8/10 на Си

Tags: c, ассемблер

Известно, что существует 4 кольца безопасности.  Как можно (и можно или в принципе) получить доступ к нулевом кольцу в современных ос Windows?  Желательно сделать это на чистом Си или на нем же со вставками кода на Assember'е
Если для этого необходимо написать драйвер, порекомендуйте какую-либо литературу по теме, пожалуйста .

Comment: "Известно, что существует 4 кольца безопасности" -- кому известно?  Какой такой "безопасности"? Если речь о защищённом режиме x86-процессоров, то, наверное, стоит начать с [этой книжки](http://www.frolov-lib.ru/books/bsp/v06/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

На сколько я помню, то драйвера используют уровень ядра windows. Это максимум как вы можете получить доступ к 0lvl.
Хотите доступ - пишите свой драйвер. kernel для того и kernel.

Comment: А как это сделать?  Если я правильно понимаю,  программу, обращающуюся в тому, кто чему доступ только у ring0, в потоке пользователя либо убьёт,  либо не запустит. То есть её надо как то особо компилидировать и линковать? Специально как-то куда-то добавлять для разрешения доступа?

Comment: @Артем Начните изучать статьи/литературу по теме написания драйверов windows. Это обширная тема. И да, вы можете это делать на C, только возьмите правильный компилятор, см. "windows wdk"